# Bootstrap - fitting nested inputs in columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have three nested input-groups as seen in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/uKCrl77t3N):

[image]

which i would like to fit on one line within the available column space without overflowing. How do i achieve this?

This is the relevant HTML for the above image:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="row form-group form-inline">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label col-lg-3 no-padding-right"><b>Expected Sales:</b></label>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="expected-sales-year-1-lbl">2017</span>
              <input type="text" pattern="[0-9.]+" id="expected-sales-year-1-value" name="expected-sales-year-1-value" placeholder="in Mt/yr">
            </div>    
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="expected-sales-year-2-lbl">2018</span>
              <input type="text" pattern="[0-9.]+" id="expected-sales-year-2-value" name="expected-sales-year-2-value" placeholder="in Mt/yr">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="expected-sales-year-3-lbl">2019</span>
              <input type="text" pattern="[0-9.]+" id="expected-sales-year-3-value" name="expected-sales-year-3-value" placeholder="in Mt/yr">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label col-lg-3 no-padding-right"><b>Price:</b></label>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-control" pattern="[0-9.]+" id="price" name="price" placeholder="in €/kg">
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

*Update*: Wrapping in a row and adding divs with `col-lg-*` around the input-groups as in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6OQ4C3RXyv) gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap them into a sub-row:

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-3 no-padding-right"><b>Expected Sales:</b></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="expected-sales-year-1-lbl"></span>
                        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9.]+" id="expected-sales-year-1-value" name="expected-sales-year-1-value" placeholder="in Mt/yr" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="expected-sales-year-2-lbl"></span>
                        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9.]+" id="expected-sales-year-2-value" name="expected-sales-year-2-value" placeholder="in Mt/yr" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="expected-sales-year-3-lbl"></span>
                        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9.]+" id="expected-sales-year-3-value" name="expected-sales-year-3-value" placeholder="in Mt/yr" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This puts the input-groups on one line but the combined width is still larger than expected (compared to the price text field; see my updated question). Also there are no spaces between the input-groups anymore. Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: That looks like you have css giving those inputs extra width, there should be a gap between each group. Do you have a live example? I can't tell for sure without seeing more css or something live.

Comment: It must be bootstrap css because even in the bootply i have this problem. I have added the bootply's to my question.

Comment: That's weird, yes i did try, see the bootply in the updated section of my question. it looks exactly the same as what you just posted, i dont see any difference except yours works. i am obviously missing something, thx for the help

Comment: ahh the `class="form-control input-control"` was missing on the inputs... thx

Comment: You had some classes missing on inputs. Classes and attributes matter a lot when working with Bootstrap, pay attention to them. I also gave .input-group a width of 100%.